# boost asio receive() vs read()

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

There are two types of reading-from-stream functions for `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`. I am assuming they their semantics vary. Could someone please outline them, the documentation I have [looked through](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) does not clarrify this.

Answer (score 10):

As it says in the documentation:

> The `receive()` operation may not receive all of the requested number of
>   bytes. Consider using the `read()` function if you need to ensure that the
>   requested amount of data is read before the blocking operation
>   completes.

If you actually meant `read_some()`, then there is no difference.  `receive()` is the socket-specific function, whereas `read_some()` is the generic function available for all asio streams.  (much like `std::string`'s `length()` and `size()`)

Comment: unfortunately that is not the correct answer. The qualification you are looking at distinguishes `free function read` from socket->read..... the same qualification is shown in socket->receive -- meaning receive should be replaced with free function read when fixed size read requests are issued.

Comment: There is no `read()` function documented for `socket`.  Do you mean `read_some()`?  In that case, there is no difference.

Comment: sorry, that is indeed what I meant. It's hard to believe that there is no difference between the two, since boost libraries go through a length incubation and peer review :(.

Comment: I compare it to `std::string::length()` and `std::string::size()`.  `receive()` is specific to `socket`, `read_some()` is generic for all asio streams.